# How can I append a folder directory with many sub directories to a QTreeView using QStandardItemModel in PyQt6

Tags: python-3.x, qtreeview, os.walk, pyqt6, qstandarditemmodel

I am building a script that takes a path and gets the folders. Then appends those folder names as items to another item that I am calling "Root". I am using QStandardItemModel and not QFileSystemModel because I intend to replace "Root" with a name that the user will provide and I am using QTreeView as a preview to the entire structure of the folder.

Current issue:

[image: Photo with current issue]

I would like to add the entire directory and include the sub directories but have it all appended under "Root". In my attempt below I am only getting the first set of folder.

In this example, I created a folder, with many sub folders and am trying to add those folders in correct order to my "Root" item.

```py
import os
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

app = QApplication([])

# Create the model
model = QStandardItemModel()

# Set the path to the directory containing the folders you want to add to the tree view
path = r"replace\with\path\to\folder"

# Create an Item for everything to parent under
root_item = QStandardItem("Root")
model.appendRow(root_item)


#iterate through the directory provided
for index,(root, folders, files) in enumerate(os.walk(path)):
    folder_root_name = (str(root))
    folder_root_name = folder_root_name.split('\\')[-1]

    for folder in folders:
        folder_item = QStandardItem(folder)
        
        if index == 0:
            root_item.appendRow(folder_item)
        else:
            folder_root_name_item = QStandardItem(folder_root_name)
            folder_root_name_item.appendRow(folder_item)


tree_view = QTreeView()
tree_view.setModel(model)
tree_view.show()
app.exec()
```

Here is a photo of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Photo of desired goal]

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [QFileSystemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfilesystemmodel.html) and [`setRootIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreeview.html#setRootIndex) along with [`index(path)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfilesystemmodel.html#index-1).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the reply, however it is my understanding that QFileSystemModel would not allow me to add an Item that doesn't exist as a folder somewhere. In my example "Root" will be replaced by the anticipated Folder name that a user supplies and I am using QTreeView as a preview for that before it happens.

Comment: Ok. For future reference, those aspects should be part of the question, as they're clearly fundamental to your needs. That said, I suggest to provide a valid [mre] of your current attempt: I know it doesn't do what you want, but at least we have some code to start with and to focus on; remember that we're here to help providing our *spare time for free*, the least you can do is to allow us to focus on the actual problem, instead of being distracted on trying to reproduce it **before** being able to help. Note: we should be able to easily copy, paste and run it (without any substantial edits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have to deal with tree/directory structures, you have to consider that you're using a 3-dimensional model, which automatically calls for a *recursive* behavior.

While, normally, such a structure would require a relative 3D "model" as a reference, a basic string-based dictionary can suffice with a simple directory-based model.

The assumption is based on the fact that `os.walk` will *always* walk through sub directories, even if they are empty.

The trick is to use a dictionary that has keys as full directory paths, and items as their values.

```py
root_item = QStandardItem("Root")
parents = {path: root_item}
model.appendRow(root_item)

def getParent(path):
    parent = parents.get(path)
    if parent:
        return parent
    grandParentPath, parentName = path.rsplit(os.sep, 1)
    parent = QStandardItem(parentName)
    parents[path] = parent
    getParent(grandParentPath).appendRow(parent)
    return parent

for root, folders, files in os.walk(path):
    getParent(root)
```